# Check if a python series contains any string in another list

Tags: python

I have a series of equal length strings of 24 characters like

```
my_series = ['ThisIsASentenceXXXXXXXXX', 'SoIsThisXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'YouGetThePointXXXXXXXXXX']
```

And I have a list also with equal length strings of 4 characters like

```
my_list = ['This', 'XXXX', 'GetT']
```

I want to compare each entry in my_list with each block of 4 characters in every entry in my_series and return the my_series items that the list string was found in.

For example for the string 'This' in my_list I would want my_series items 1 and 2 returned and for 'XXXX' my_series items 1,2,3 would be returned.

Comment: have you tried anything to achieve this? maybe you can provide us an example of what you have tried along with any error messages. otherwise, refer to  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: not gonna help too much but something like if my_list[0] in my_series[0]:

Answer (score 3):

The following generator will create a 2 dimensional list. Each list will contain any matches, and it's position will match to the my_list index.

```
n_list = [[x for x in my_series if item in x] for item in my_list]
```

Output:

> > [['ThisIsASentenceXXXXXXXXX', 'SoIsThisXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'], ['ThisIsASentenceXXXXXXXXX', 'SoIsThisXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'YouGetThePointXXXXXXXXXX'], ['YouGetThePointXXXXXXXXXX']]

therefore `n_list[0]` contains matches for `my_list[0]` etc...
I hope this helped you out!

Answer (score -1):

You need to split each entries in the `my_series` into 6 chunks:

```
serires_chunks = [(s[0:4], s[4:8], s[8:12], s[12:16], s[16:20], s[20:24])
                  for s in my_series]
```

Then you can iterate over this chunks to find the matching items:

```
for item in my_list:
    for index, chunks in enumerate(serires_chunks):
        for place, chunk in enumerate(chunks, 1):
            if item == chunk:
                location = my_series[index]
                print("Found '{item}' in '{location}' at {place}".format(**locals()))
```

You'll obtain:

```
Found 'This' in 'ThisIsASentenceXXXXXXXXX' at 1
Found 'This' in 'SoIsThisXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' at 2
Found 'XXXX' in 'ThisIsASentenceXXXXXXXXX' at 5
Found 'XXXX' in 'ThisIsASentenceXXXXXXXXX' at 6
Found 'XXXX' in 'SoIsThisXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' at 3
Found 'XXXX' in 'SoIsThisXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' at 4
Found 'XXXX' in 'SoIsThisXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' at 5
Found 'XXXX' in 'SoIsThisXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' at 6
Found 'XXXX' in 'YouGetThePointXXXXXXXXXX' at 5
Found 'XXXX' in 'YouGetThePointXXXXXXXXXX' at 6
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the desired output the OP was looking for.